# How to change upload_to parameter of ImageField based on field name in Django?

Tags: django, models, filefield, imagefield

I would like to upload images to the media root based on the field values given by the Django admin user. Here is the code that I've written and I know that the upload_to parameter is causing the problem. But I don't know how to make it work.

## models.py

```
class Info(models.Model):
    file_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateField()
    area = models.IntegerField(default=0.00)
    mouja = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doc_type_choices = (
            ('deed', 'Deed'),
            ('khotian', 'Khotian'),
        )
    doc_type = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                choices=doc_type_choices,
                                default='deed')
    doc_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file_no

class Image(models.Model):
    info = models.ForeignKey('Info')
    content = models.ImageField(upload_to=self.info.mouja/self.info.doc_type)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.info.file_no
```

Whenever I run *python manage.py makemigrations* it shows *NameError: name 'self' is not defined*
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `upload_to` keyword you would need to provide a function that you will define, for instance:

```
def path_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(filter(None, (instance.info.mouja, instance.info.doc_type, filename)))

class Image(models.Model):
    content = models.ImageField(upload_to=path_file_name)
```

From [Django documentation: Model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

> This may also be a callable, such as a function, which will be called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. This callable must be able to accept two arguments, and return a Unix-style path (with forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system.

Within this callable, which in the particular case is `path_file_name` function, we build a path from the `instance` field which is the particular record of `Image` model.

The `filter` function removes any `None` items out of the list and the `join` function constructs the path by joining all list items with `/`.

Comment: `os.path.join` would be a lot better here.

Comment: Actually the first code worked but this new code is not working. Gives this error --> AttributeError at /admin/index/info/add/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'rfind'

Comment: I can't see any `rfind` in the code provided, is this relevant? What is the exact error and where?

Comment: The error occurs when I press 'Save' in the Django Admin after I input all the data. Here is a bigger version of the error --> AttributeError at /admin/index/info/add/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'rfind'
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/index/info/add/
Django Version: 1.8.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'tuple' object has no attribute 'rfind'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py in split, line 92
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6

Comment: Is there any reference to your code in the traceback and django's, and what exactly it says? This particular method that I recommended is the one that I extensively use so I find it hard to be wrong.

Comment: I rolled back to the initial answer. Maybe `os.path.join` is better here, but this one I have tested as well it seems.

Comment: No reference anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I don't understand how this code works. Can you direct me to an article from where I can learn about the syntax you used?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the original code that worked. Just in case anyone needs it.

```
def path_file_name(instance, filename):
    return '/'.join(filter(None, (instance.info.mouja, instance.info.doc_type, filename)))
```