# How to change the name of image while uploading

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-errors

**models.py**

```
def productFile(instance, request, filename):
    old_name = str(filename)
    new_name = "http://" + str(request.get_host()) + "/"+ str(instance.id)+".png"
    renamed_image = os.rename(old_name, new_name)
    return 'profile/'.join( [renamed_image] )

class User(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    otp = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    profile_dp = models.ImageField(upload_to = productFile ,null=True, blank=True)
    profile_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static']

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR /'static/images'
```

**Required Output**

When i upload image in profile_dp the name image name should change into this format(`"http://" + str(request.get_host()) + "/"+ str(instance.id)+".png"`)

**Error i am getting**

`productFile()` missing 1 required positional argument: `'filename'`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include the full error traceback.

Comment: Might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30349547/how-to-change-upload-to-parameter-of-imagefield-based-on-field-name-in-django

Comment: productfile() function is not getting the filename